# what is the meaning of this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
declare
@hitung int,
@salesid int,
@ulang int = 0

select @hitung=count(distinct person.person.BusinessEntityID),
@salesid = min(distinct Person.Person.BusinessEntityID)
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
inner join person.person 
on Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = Person.person.BusinessEntityID
```

I want to know what is the meaning of count(distinct person.person.businessEntityID). and the meaning of min(distinct person.person.businessentityid)

i'm using adventureworks2008 as my test for Query above

Comment: This looks like T-SQL (SQL Server), not like a valid MySQL query.

Comment: AdventureWorks is a Microsoft demo DB so I'd say you are right, this isn't MySql

Comment: the instructor give me this query to test my skill to analyze the query so i don't really know if it's a valid or not. i just need to analyze it and decipher it

Comment: So you asked stackoverflow to analyze it instead?

Comment: Run a few tests yourself to see whats going on.  Maybe start with `select person.person.BusinessEntityID...` then try  `select DISTINCT person.person.BusinessEntityID...` and see what the difference in record count is etc. Not sure why you've got an **upvote** for this!? *this question shows research effort*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is counting the unique values for `person.person.BusinessEntityID` and getting the lowest `person.person.BusinessEntityID` value.

So if the table contains for `person.person.BusinessEntityID` the values

```
1001
1002
1001
1003
1002

count(person.person.BusinessEntityID) = 5 // all
count(distinct person.person.BusinessEntityID) = 3 //1001, 1002, 1003
min(person.person.BusinessEntityID) = 1001
min( distinct person.person.BusinessEntityID) = 1001
```

Comment: what about the distinct part sir ?

Comment: Distinct looks only at the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

The original query involves joining two tables but where one table isn't required for the count or for the minimum value. In fact the query has been made much more complex that it needs to be because of that join. This would produce the same outcome without the redundancies:

```
declare
@hitung int,
@salesid int,
@ulang int = 0

select @hitung=count(person.person.BusinessEntityID),
@salesid = min(Person.Person.BusinessEntityID)
from person.person 
where exists (select 1
              from Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
              where Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = Person.person.BusinessEntityID
             )
```

**BUT:** In addition consider the correctness of a SalesOrderID being equal to BusinessEntityID
this requires that every order placed by a person will have the same SalesOrderID.

This relationship (Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = Person.person.BusinessEntityID) does not appear to be logical and throws the whole query into question.

Comment: okay sir, your explanation is really helpful. thanks a lot for alternative query you provide to correct my query.